# Code in comment is all on one line

Tags: support, comments, markdown

[My comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719164/type-error-in-haskell-program#comment-6540097) on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719164/type-error-in-haskell-program/5719198#5719198) has all the code on one line:

> ninjagecko unfortunatelly Your code doesn't work for me. I have changed my code and now it works (unfortunatelly i don't know how I can write code in comment - why all code is in one line ?): `main = do db <- loadFile "db.txt" mainMenu db mainMenu rs = do putStrLn "Choose option:" n <- getLine case n of "1" -> do menuRectangles rs; mainMenu rs "2" -> putStrLn "bye, bye" otherwise -> do putStrLn "Bad option"; mainMenu rs`

Why is it displayed that way? It looks horrible

Comment: Stack Overflow does have ways to properly format code.  You can always use the braces in the toolbar above the answer box and see what you get.

Comment: That's your second question on this subject posted (wrongly) on stackoverflow. This type of questions should be posted on the meta website, only after reading the documentation from the FAQ.

Comment: So how I can show multi-line code in comment ? I won't click SHIFT + ENTER 100 times in each line.

Comment: **Read my answer.** You cannot show multi-line code in comments because you cannot write multi-line comments. In the case of the question you linked, you can add that code as an edit to your original question.

Comment: Thx for answer Matt. May I know why you don't want to allow users write multi-line comments ?

Comment: @user160517: Because the body of the question / answer is for substantial content relevant to the problem / solution.

Comment: If you need to add code **edit** your question or answer.

Answer (score 8):

Because that's Stack Exchange comments work: you only get to a newline by line wrapping.

> [Multiple lines are not supported in comments, and will never be.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34141/)